# Assembly x64 adding two numbers

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I have a problem, why this assembly code of mine does not print "50"? Is it already printing "2"? I don't understand why, I'm new to the assembly world of programming, so any help would be great.

```
section .data 
    num1 dq 30
    num2 dq 20
    result dq 0

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, [num1]
    add rax, [num2]
    add [result], rax

    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, result
    mov rdx, 8 
    syscall

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

Comment: The write syscall does not print numbers. You need to convert to text. `50` happens to be the ascii code of `2` so that's why you get that.